# How to hijack submit to add values?

Tags: redux-form

I have a form that can have different state based on which button was used for submission; one does a simple submit while the other one adds a flag then submit.
I found a working solution that is, imo, quite ugly, so I'd like to know how else to do it ?

```
class MyForm extends Component {
  // Hijack submit to add published flag
  handlePublish = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { handleSubmit, onSubmit } = this.props;
    handleSubmit((values) => {
      onSubmit({
        ...values,
        isPublished: true,
      });
    })();
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field
          name="foo"
          component="input"
        />

        <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={this.handlePublish}
        >
          Publish
        </button>

        <button type="submit">
          Save
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

✅ This is the idiomatic way. Alternatively, you could provide any number of values as `initialValues` that don't actually have a `Field` on the form, but will be submitted.

Comment: Thanks, it looks a bit to redundant imo but it's working well.